# How to find all Sun Sat on command line

Tags: command-line

This works on Ubuntu but not on Mac.

```
$ seq -f %1.0f 20210101 20211231 | date -f - 2>/dev/null | grep 'Sun\|Sat'
...
Sat Dec 18 00:00:00 JST 2021
Sun Dec 19 00:00:00 JST 2021
Sat Dec 25 00:00:00 JST 2021
Sun Dec 26 00:00:00 JST 2021
```

How to find all Sat and Sun from command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macOS/BSD version of `date` can't read from standard input so you need to loop manually.

```
for d in $(seq -f %1.0f 20210101 20211231); do 
    date -jf "%Y%m%d" $d 2>/dev/null | grep 'Sat\|Sun'
done
```

You can avoid most of the impossible dates created by `seq` (and get the result faster) by running

```
for m in {01..12}; do
    for d in {01..31}; do
        date -jf "%Y%m%d" "2021${m}${d}" 2>/dev/null
    done
done | grep 'Sat\|Sun'
```

Comment: Thanks. As you mentioned the second one is much faster. I didn't know that macOS/BSD version of date can't read from standard input.

Comment: @shin I find Man pages (e.g. `man date`) to be extremely helpful when porting shell scripts from Linux.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119706/discussion-on-answer-by-nohillside-how-to-find-all-sun-sat-on-command-line).